# Plot real time data into line chart

Tags: javascript, html, plot

I have some data collected in real time that I want to plot to line charts.

I would like to plot the data received in say last 60 calls into a line chart(pause plotting when not pulling data), each name:value pair gets 1 chart(so there would be 6 charts in this case).  Of course I need to update the charts every second or every time `httpGet()` gets called.

I am not sure how to proceed to next step after I have got response(the data to plot) from the server...the end I am looking for is pretty much something "CPU usage history" style.

Here is my JavaScript file for collecting data from an aggregation server:

```
//httpGet() adopted from SO/247483
function httpGet()
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "foo.com/sensordata", false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

var interval;

//this is called by a button in the html file
function start(btn)
{
    if(btn.value=="Start"){
        interval = setInterval(httpGet, 1000);
        btn.value="Stop";
    } else {
        btn.value="Start";
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

So clicking the "Start" button will start making GET requests for data every 1 second. Server returns data in JSON format, this is an example output from console:

```
{
    "Time":"2015/06/04 18:35:39",
    "SensorA":{"Value1":0.34804,"Value2":-0.39175,"Value3":-0.61718},
    "SensorB":{"Value1":516,"Value2":1,"Value2":2103}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: which values you want in your chart? please specify the x and y axis mapping

Answer (score 0):

I've made [this demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/2D3W9ZD9) (be sure to click on the Start Feed button!) that uses ZingChart. In the callback for the get request, I loop through the data and put it into the right format for ZingChart, then when it's all scrubbed, I use the [modify](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__modify) method to set the `values` attribute in `scale-x`, which takes an array of Unix time values in milliseconds, and the [setseriesvalues](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__setseriesvalues) method to update the data in the chart.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    zingchart.exec('myChart','modify',{
        update:false,
        data:{
            "scale-x":{
                "values":dataObj.date
            }
        }
    });
    zingchart.exec('myChart','setseriesvalues',{
        update:false,
        graphid:i,
        values:[dataObj[Object.keys(dataObj)[(i + 1)]]]
    });
}
zingchart.exec('myChart','update');
```

Since I'm calling modify and setseriesvalues a bunch of times in a row, I set the `update` option on both to `false`, which queues up the changes, with everything that has been queued being pushed to the chart when `update` is called.

(Yeah, I do fake the data here -- I'm alternating between two different JSON files, but you should get the idea.)